# Magento : fatal error when installing the Hardwood theme

Tags: php, magento

I tried to install the Hardwood theme but I got this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /volume1/web/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 555

Here is the code near line 555 :

```
public function getOutput()
    {
        $out = '';
        if (!empty($this->_output)) {
            foreach ($this->_output as $callback) {
                $out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback[1]();
            }
        }

        return $out;
    }
```

What should I change in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Near* line 555?  Which one *is* line 555?

A very hackish approach would be to add a call to is_object(), but you don't want to do that.  What you want is for the theme author to fix his theme.

```
public function getOutput()
    {
        $out = '';
        if (!empty($this->_output)) {
            foreach ($this->_output as $callback) {
                //hack
                if (is_object($callback)) {
                   $out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback[1]();
                } //end hack
            }
        }

        return $out;
    }
```

Comment: Again, I reiterate, you don't want to do this.  Why?  Several reasons, the chief of which it's bad practice.  But a practical reason ... you'll have to re-do this hack every time you update your Magento installation....

Get some support from the Hardwood developer!! ;-)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it doesn't work and I'm not good enough to see what's wrong with it... But anyway, you're right, I'd better check with the developer if he can do something about it

Answer (score 0):

Old PHP versions accepted $callback[] in expressions, allowed reading out the $callback content regardless of syntax. PHP 5.1 made that illegal.
In case of object attribute you can wrap your $callback inside { }.

```
public function getOutput()
{
    $out = '';
    if (!empty($this->_output)) {
        foreach ($this->_output as $callback) {
            $out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->${callback[1]}();
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```

My magento theme was Carstore, which is outdated but that is the one I had to work with because my client bought it.
Link to my theme: http://themeforest.net/item/accessories-car-magento-theme/662796?s_rank=1